# Log shipping - Secondary Server

Tags: restore, sql-server-2017, log-shipping

I am not a SQL Server DBA but I need some advise. I am having a problem with a prod server that’s being pounded by constant queries and data mining. I have a second server that I would like to setup to have a copy of production but on a day lag.

I know I can restore a backup from prod once a day but the proble is prod is in Azure and it takes 4 hrs to download the bkup.

So I am thinking log shipping except I want to control how the logs are applied so as to end up with just the prior day’s transactions every day.

Any suggestions as to how this can be accomplished would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need more information. 1. what is the Azure offering you are using? 2. database size 3. WHere would be the secondary? please provide all necessary details.

Comment: Are you using AzCopy to download the backup?  It's quite a bit faster than other methods that I've seen.  (Assumes you are backing up to a blob/file storage account).    Otherwise, have you looked into https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/databaserestore-open-source-database-restore-stored-procedure/ ?